# Generate variable containing number of characters in a string variable

Tags: stata

In a survey dataset I have a string variable (type: `str244`) with qualitative responses. I want to count the number of characters in each response/string and generate a new variable containing this number.

Using the `egenmore` I have already counted the number of words using `nwords`, but I cannot find the counterpart for counting characters.

EXAMPLE:

```
egen countvar = nwords(stringvar)
```

where `countvar` is the new variable name and `stringvar` is the string variable.

Does such an `egen` function exist for counting characters?

Comment: The function `wordcount()` in Stata makes the older add-on `nwords()` redundant. Note `egenmore` is downloaded using `ssc inst egenmore`.

Comment: The help for `egenmore` does point to `wordcount()`. N.B. `nwords()` (written for Stata 6) is very slow.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this. `gen countvar = wordcount(stringvar)` works like a charm. I wasn't aware that `wordcount` was used with `gen`, not `egen`. Perfect!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no `egen` function because there has long [sic] been a function strict sense to do this. In recent versions of Stata, the function is called `strlen()` but the older name `length()` continues to work:

```
. sysuse auto
(1978 Automobile Data)

. gen l1 = length(make)

. gen l2 = strlen(make)

. su l?

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
          l1 |         74    11.77027    2.155257          6         17
          l2 |         74    11.77027    2.155257          6         17
```

See `help functions` and [(e.g.) this tutorial column](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0058).

Comment: What about for counting digits in a numeric variable?

Comment: That's a new question really as there are subtle differences. Do you mean integers or you include decimal parts?  If you mean integers, `log10(x) + 1` is a good start.  If you include numbers with decimal parts, the question is a lot messier without knowing a display format.

Answer (score -1):

```
. sysuse auto,clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. tostring price, gen(price1)
price1 generated as str5

. gen l3=length(price1)

. sum l3

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max

          l3 |         74    4.135135    .3442015          4          5
```

Comment: in case u want the count of numeric variable

Comment: This has to seem naive. See my comment underneath my answer. The "length" of a numeric variable is well defined only in certain cases. In your example, `price` is reported as a positive integer, and for that you don't need to convert to a string variable. You just need to push the maximum value through `ceil(log10())`. Your code could be problematic for variables in which any numeric value was negative or contained fractional parts, depending on precision issues and what you want precisely.